# Check if user is associated in m2m

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've created a simple 'favourites' system in my django app. I have `events` which can be faved by any logged in user. What i'm trying to do is somehow check if current logged-in user has faved currently looped event.

It would be quite easy if i could make it in my `views.py` file but i need to check it directly in template or in a model (in which i can't get currently logged-in user data).

My `Event` model looks like that:

```
...
class Event(models.Model):
        ...
    users_faved = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='users_faved', blank=True)
```

If i would be able to access currently logged in user data from Model, i would create a new object called, for example, `is_faved()` which would be called from a template that way:

```
{% for event in evemts_list %}
  {{ event.is_faved }}
{% endfor %}
```

But as i've mentioned before, i'm not able to access current logged in user data. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags), that takes an event and the user as an argument.